# Pausing a Thread on PyGTK

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject, gobject

I have a button that when it is clicked, it starts a GObject thread that calls a function every 2 seconds. I want to have **another button that pauses or stops the calling of this function.** Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Using Python GTK 3

```
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self,widget):
    print("Data..")
    self.th = GObject.timeout_add(2000,self.refresh_screen)

def on_pausebutton_clicked(self,widget):
    print("Paused..")
```

Comment: Found my answer. I have to use GObject.source_remove(self.th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Revome the source!

```
def on_refreshbutton_clicked(self,widget):
    print("Data..")
    self.th = GObject.timeout_add(2000,self.refresh_screen)

def on_pauseButton_clicked(self, widget):
    print("Paused main screen.")
    GObject.source_remove(self.th)
```

Comment: Another solution would be to have a special variable and check it in `refresh_screen`. If you want to pause, `return GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE`, if you want to stop, `return GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE `

Comment: Got it. Thanks!